# TLS socket hangs on during handshake

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, openssl, nonblocking

We have a server application (developed in C++) where multiple clients connect and communicate with messages using TLS (using OpenSSL) over TCP protocol. During the first connection attempt for some clients, we observed a strange behavior such that the receiver thread of the application hangs on during the TLS initial handshake (Note that there is no problem in the TCP layer i.e. socket accept method). The code fragment can be seen like:

```
int dd = accept(socket, (sockaddr*)&ss, (socklen_t*)&len); // no problem in TCP socket accept
/* some additional code here */
cout << "Trace line 1" << endl;
BIO_set_nbio (pBio, 1);  // set BIO as non-blocking
int flags = fcntl(socket, F_GETFL, 0); // set TCP socket non-blocking
fcntl(socket, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

int res = SSL_accept(TheSsl);  // calling TLS accept 

flags = fcntl(socket, F_GETFL, 0); // set TCP socket blocking again
fcntl(socket, F_SETFL, flags & ~O_NONBLOCK);
BIO_set_nbio(pBio, 0); // set BIO blocking again    
cout << "Trace line 2" << endl;
```

We assumed that we have been using non-blocking I/O for TLS handshake operation, is that usage above correct for handling such issues? The time interval between "Trace line 1" and "Trace line 2" changes randomly i.e. sometimes around 16 minutes, sometimes much more than 16 minutes. In such cases, we observed that the res value is -1 and the error value provided by OpenSSL is SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL. Which code part can take such an enormous time for this operation? Can this depend on the specific state or any other specifics of that client? Any comment would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using non-blocking I/O with OpenSSL is not easy. Why are you using non-blocking I/O at all? In any case, you need to call `ssl_accept()` in a loop until it finishes its work. If `ssl_accept()` returns 1, it is done successfully and you can move on. Otherwise, anything else is an error, and you have to call `SSL_get_error()` to find out why it failed. If `SSL_get_error()` returns `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` or `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`, you need to handle those conditions (which usually involves calls to `select()`) and then call `ssl_accept()` again, otherwise fail your code and close the socket connec

Comment: Actually we are trying to use non-blocking sockets respectively TLS I/O due to the reason that is mentioned above. One client handshake blocks the server message receiver thread for a while and thus other clients cannot connect to the server. The main concern here is that: why does this operation take too much time? Which code part might cause that blocking issue?